# phonegap create test not working

Tags: software-installation, npm

I installed node.js and npm on my Ubuntu 14.04 system using:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

I then tried to install phonegap with `npm install -g phonegap`.

Everything seemed fine, but when I try run `phonegap create test` nothing happens.
It just returns a non zero error,  but doesn't display any specific error.

I did exactly how what the instructions suggested, still no luck!

Can anyone tell what am I missing?

Comment: Please help us help you by providing us with the instructions you followed.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I had installed node package earlier sometime, due to which it was conflicting. So you just need to remove the old node package then `sudo apt-get install nodejs` then install phonegap via npm and you're ready to go. And you need to have your android development tools in your $PATH variable so that phonegap can trigger them properly.

Answer (score -1):

You can also find PhoneGap / Cordova command over here http://goo.gl/3iu7SF

Comment: While technically this provides an answer, it is generally good practice to include a brief description of what's included in the linked article. This way if the link becomes unavailable, your answer will remain useful.